# Can I integrate Facebook Comments with the native WordPress comment system?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wordpress

I recently started work on an existing WordPress site, and one of the requests from the client is to install Facebook Comments.  The blog already has existing comments using WordPress' native Commenting system and we don't want to lose the old comments.  Is this possible to do?

If I use the standard [Facebook Comment app](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) I will be replacing the existing WordPress comments.  Technically I could keep both by listing the WordPress comments after the Facebook comments but this is not a viable solution in this case.

I also saw the [Facebook Comments for WordPress](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-comments-for-wordpress) plugin but it has not been updated in almost a year, and 15/20 people say that the app is broken with the latest version of WordPress.

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks for reading!

**Edit**:  Since making this post, the most recent version of JetPack has added in WordPress comments, which includes the ability for people to login with their Facebook account.  I have since been using that, and found it to be the best solution for my current needs.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-connect/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it looks like this plugin will only replace the WordPress native commenting, whereas I am trying to merge the two.  It looks like I might need to get creative, heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could keep both by listing the WordPress comments after the
>   Facebook comments but this is not a viable solution in this case.

You've answered your own question. Simply style the old comments to look exactly like the new comments and no one will be the wiser.

Comment: I actually ended up going with a simple Facebook Connect option instead, but you are 100% right and that's a perfect solution for this scenario.  Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

The official Facebook plugin is the best for replacing tghe native WordPress comments system with Facebook comments.

I use it on my own site about WordPress.

The other plugins simply add Facebook comments to WordPress without replacing the default WordPress comments system so you end up with 2 comments systems.

The Facebook Developers plugin can also be used however you need to edit your template files to make it work.